# How to find the 95% confidence interval when there is outliers?

Tags: confidence-interval, estimation, statsmodels

I know how to find the 95% confidence interval for normal distributions. But how to find it **when there is outliers**?

Question: The health-care costs, in thousands of dollars for 20 males aged 75 or over, are shown in data set. Calculate the 95% confidence interval on the mean health-care cost for such individuals.

Data set = [8.5, 8.0, 16.0, 12.0, 2.5, 515.0, 5.0, 15.0, 13.0, 2.0, 950.0, 15.0, 9.0, 6.0, 12.0, 5.5, 19.5, 7.5, 37.5, 12.5]

Comment: How many observations? How many outliers? Outliers all is same direction? Can you give an example? (Converted to standard scores $(X_i - \bar X)/S$ to avoid disclosure, if necessary.)

Comment: 2 Observations,   2 outliers and same direction

Comment: How many observations _altogether_? Got an appointment now. Check back in 4-5 hrs.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake.. 20 observations.

Comment: A confidence interval *for what population characteristic*? The mean or can it be some other measure of location?

Comment: Health-care costs, in thousands of dollars for 20 males.

Comment: But are you exclusively interested in a confidence interval for the true *mean* or are you open to other location parameters like the median? (I don't think so because it is about costs...)

Answer (score 4):

Quick preliminary results from R:

```
x=c(8.5, 8.0, 16.0, 12.0, 2.5, 515.0, 5.0, 15.0, 13.0, 2.0, 
    950.0, 15.0, 9.0, 6.0, 12.0, 5.5, 19.5, 7.5, 37.5, 12.5)

summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.000   7.125  12.000  83.575  15.250 950.000
```

(1) t interval for mean. Assumes normal data, which seems a bad assumption here.

```
t.test(x)
...
95 percent confidence interval:
  -25.47337 192.62337
```

(2) Nonparametric Wilcoxon CI for population median. May be slightly inaccurate because of ties
in your data.

```
wilcox.test(x, conf.int=T)
...
95 percent confidence interval:
  8.500058 21.750047
```

(3) 95% nonparamatric bootstrap quantile CI for population mean: $(10, 200).$

```
set.seed(2020)
a.re=replicate(10^4, mean(sample(x, rep=T)))
quantile(a.re, c(.025,.975))
    2.5%    97.5% 
  9.9750 200.5269
```

Leave comments/questions as appropriate. More later.

Comment: Since the sample is small, bootstrap results won't be very precise, but what else (if it is about the mean) would... Still, I'd prefer *bootstrap t* over a naive percentile bootstrap.

Comment: @MichaelM.  agree t based bootstrap is generally better as CI for $\mu,$ but results about the same as for naive in this case.

Comment: @Sadisha: Do you know if there is literature on families distributions of health-care costs (exponential, Pareto, etc.) If so, it might be a good idea to see if there is a distribution-specific style of CI that would work better for your data. // Are you familiar with bootstrap CIs? Comfortable using it here without further explanation? Seems to give a sensible result for your data. // Because health care costs are real money to be paid by someone, and the mean is based on total expenditure, the mean makes more sense to me here than median.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap might be one way to do this.  In python...

```py
from sklearn.utils import resample
import numpy as np


x = np.array([8.5, 8.0, 16.0, 12.0, 2.5, 515.0, 5.0, 15.0, 13.0, 2.0, 950.0, 15.0, 9.0, 6.0, 12.0, 5.5, 19.5, 7.5, 37.5, 12.5])

xb = np.array([ resample(x).mean() for j in range(10000)])

low, high = np.quantile(xb, [0.025, 0.975])
```

This yields a bootstrap CI of  (9.95 , 200.72).

However, I think there is something driving higher costs.  Because your data are from older patients, I imagine some patients have more co-morbidities than others which may lead to complications and hence higher costs.  In the absence if additional information, or strong assumptions on the data generating processes, I think this is going to be the best you can do.